# How to substitute nan by 0 in numpy arrays to calculate mean values?

Tags: python, numpy

How to substitute NaN by zero in te following set of data?: My goal is to make the following estimation, assuming that `matches` is the dataset given below:

```
# average the data
avg = {}
for k, v in matches.items():
    avg[k] = sum(v) / float(len(v))
print(avg)
```

The content of `matches`:

```
{('AD', 'MM', 'TT'): [], ('AD', 'MM', 'VV'): [array([54.0, 97.0, 160.0, nan, 9.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan], dtype=object), array([176.0, 68.0, 166.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan], dtype=object), array([nan, 55.0, 176.0, nan, 34.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan], dtype=object), array([38.0, 72.0, 466.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan], dtype=object), array([62.0, 20.0, 397.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan], dtype=object), array([40.0, 31.0, 94.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan], dtype=object), array([104.0, 70.0, 338.0, nan, 19.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan], dtype=object), array([99.0, 62.0, 401.0, nan, 37.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan], dtype=object), array([53.0, 109.0, 262.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan], dtype=object), array([45.0, 55.0, 159.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan], dtype=object), array([80.0, 104.0, 438.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan], dtype=object), array([81.0, 75.0, 141.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan], dtype=object), array([140.0, 43.0, 192.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan], dtype=object), array([72.0, 26.0, 704.0, nan, 57.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan], dtype=object), array([67.0, 49.0, 210.0, nan, 20.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan], dtype=object), array([122.0, 67.0, 546.0, nan, 25.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan], dtype=object), array([130.0, 61.0, 400.0, nan, 20.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan], dtype=object), array([88.0, 133.0, 354.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan], dtype=object), array([77.0, 42.0, 212.0, nan, 31.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan], dtype=object), array([138.0, 64.0, 132.0, nan, 49.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan], dtype=object)]}
```

Comment: Look at `np.nanmean`.  But when I try it one one of your `object` arrays I get `nan`.  If I change the array to `dtype=float`, I get a proper nan-less mean.

Comment: do you mean this? `for k, v in matches.items():
    avg[k] = np.nanmean(v)`. It outputs `nan` for all `v`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299093/how-to-calculate-mean-values-over-columns-in-a-given-data-structure asks about the mean for a similar dictionary containing lists of object dtype arrays.  Change the `axis` parameter for the `mean` function if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`numpy.nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) calculates a mean, ignoring all NaNs; in your case, this produces the result below

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: matches = {('AD', 'MM', 'TT'): [], ('AD', 'MM', 'VV'): [[54.0, 97.0, 160.0, np.nan, 9.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 
   ...: np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [176.0, 68.0, 166.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.
   ...: nan, np.nan], [np.nan, 55.0, 176.0, np.nan, 34.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [38.0,
   ...:  72.0, 466.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [62.0, 20.0, 397.0, np.nan
   ...: , np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [40.0, 31.0, 94.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.
   ...: nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [104.0, 70.0, 338.0, np.nan, 19.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 
   ...: np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [99.0, 62.0, 401.0, np.nan, 37.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan
   ...: , np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [53.0, 109.0, 262.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, n
   ...: p.nan], [45.0, 55.0, 159.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [80.0, 104.0
   ...: , 438.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [81.0, 75.0, 141.0, np.nan, np.
   ...: nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [140.0, 43.0, 192.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan
   ...: , np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [72.0, 26.0, 704.0, np.nan, 57.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.n
   ...: an, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [67.0, 49.0, 210.0, np.nan, 20.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np
   ...: .nan, np.nan, np.nan], [122.0, 67.0, 546.0, np.nan, 25.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
   ...: , [130.0, 61.0, 400.0, np.nan, 20.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [88.0, 133.0, 354.0
   ...: , np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [77.0, 42.0, 212.0, np.nan, 31.0, np.n
   ...: an, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [138.0, 64.0, 132.0, np.nan, 49.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, n
   ...: p.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]]}
   ...: 
   ...: avg = {k: np.nanmean(v) for k, v in matches.items()}
   ...: avg
   ...: 
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py:703: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice
  warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice", RuntimeWarning)
Out[1]: {('AD', 'MM', 'TT'): nan, ('AD', 'MM', 'VV'): 133.59420289855072}
```