# How to calculate mean values over columns in a given data structure?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have the following data structure `ds`:

```
{('AD', 'TYPE_B', 'TYPE_D'): [array([84.0, 85.0, 115.0], dtype=object), array([31.0, 23.0, 599.0], dtype=object), array([75.0, 21.0, nan], dtype=object), array([59.0, 52.0, 29.0], dtype=object)],('AD', 'TYPE_A', 'TYPE_N'): [array([84.0, 85.0, 115.0], dtype=object), array([31.0, 23.0, 599.0], dtype=object), array([75.0, 21.0, 300.0], dtype=object), array([59.0, 52.0, 29.0], dtype=object)]}
```

I need to estimate mean values over the first column, the second column and the third column per each key (i.e. `('AD', 'TYPE_B', 'TYPE_D')` and `('AD', 'TYPE_A', 'TYPE_N')`).

Some arrays like `array([75.0, 21.0, nan]` contain `nan` strings that I want to substitute by 0.

For example, for the key `('AD', 'TYPE_B', 'TYPE_D')` the following results should be achieved (explained step by step):

Step 1:

```
84.0 85.0 115.0
31.0 23.0 599.0
75.0 21.0 nan
59.0 52.0 29.0
```

Step 2:

```
84.0 85.0 115.0
31.0 23.0 599.0
75.0 21.0 0
59.0 52.0 29.0
```

Step 3 (the final result):

```
('AD', 'TYPE_B', 'TYPE_D'): [62.25, 45.25, 185.75]
```

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable, although you don't really need two steps. What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the built-in functions from numpy.

```
import numpy as np

ds = {('AD', 'TYPE_B', 'TYPE_D'): [np.array([84.0, 85.0, 115.0], dtype=object), 
                                   np.array([31.0, 23.0, 599.0], dtype=object), 
                                   np.array([75.0, 21.0, np.nan], dtype=object), 
                                   np.array([59.0, 52.0, 29.0], dtype=object)],
      ('AD', 'TYPE_A', 'TYPE_N'): [np.array([84.0, 85.0, 115.0], dtype=object), 
                                   np.array([31.0, 23.0, 599.0], dtype=object), 
                                   np.array([75.0, 21.0, 300.0], dtype=object), 
                                   np.array([59.0, 52.0, 29.0], dtype=object)]}

for key in ds.keys():
    #first cast to float and replace nan
    item    = np.nan_to_num(np.asarray(ds[key], dtype=np.float64));
    #calculate the mean
    mean    = np.mean(item, axis=0)
    #store it in the dictionary
    ds[key] = mean

print ds
```

Comment: Converting the individual `object` arrays into a 2d `float` array is the critical step.  The `nan` replacement doesn't work when the elements are `objects`.